# Textbox background color not applying from Style

Tags: wpf, xaml, background

My textbox is in `WPF` User control and style is being applied as:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MyStyles1;component/Themes/MyTheme.xaml"/>
```

**Style is as follows:**

```
<Style x:Key="OutputTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
<Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
<Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
<Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
<Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
<Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="15" />
<Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
</Style>
```

It is noted that all properties(e.g. Foreground, BorderBrush, BorderThickness etc) are working as required. **But TextBox Background is not applied.**

Please assist.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of setting this style to text boxes:

1. Explicitly using:

   ```
   <TextBox Style="{StaticResource OutputTextBoxStyle}" />
   ```

   This is the usual way when only a few text boxes in the project need this style applying to them.
2. Implicitly using implicit styles. To get implicit styles working your definition shouldn't contain an `x:Key` definition.

   So you either add a second definition like this:

   ```
   <Style TargetType="TextBox"
          BasedOn="{StaticResource OutputTextBoxStyle}" />
   ```

   or remove the `x:Key` definition from your existing style.

   You'll need to do the former if you ever want to explicitly reference the style from somewhere else.

You can also override a specific part of the style by specifying it:

```
<TextBox Style="{StaticResource OutputTextBoxStyle}"
         Background="{Aqua}" />
```

or

```
<TextBox Background="{Aqua}" />
```

Comment: I need explicitly refer the style. So I should give an x:Key.
But strangely the background is again showing as White when I set to Green.
TextBox is defined as 
<TextBox MinWidth="45" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource OutputTextBoxStyle}"></TextBox>

Comment: @Singh - When I set the style explicitly it worked fine. Do you have anything else that might be overriding the background?

Comment: I can confirm that there is no other style is defined for textbox in the project anywhere else. Do you have any hints for me to check overriding?

Just FYI, am using Prism UnityBootstrapper, Modules and accessing the style from Module project(just to check if these have any impact on this behaviour).

Comment: @Singh - other than looking for an explicit `Background="{...}"` on the offending text box, no.

Comment: Sorry, am not clear on your last reply? Checked giving a color directly to textbox background and it worked fine. Also we dont have any more Background="{..}" in the project.

Comment: @Singh that's what I meant. So you're sure that the only code setting the background is this style and that this style is applied to all textboxes?

Comment: No, just for testing I have applied BackGround property as <TextBox MinWidth="45" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Background="Aqua" ></TextBox>.
So no code is there to set it back.

I need only a couple of textboxes to be in this style not all textboxes.

Comment: Also, it is noticed that expected Green background is setting correct in design time, but in runtime it is changing back to white.

Comment: I think I spotted out the root cause. The project was using Telerik ResourceDirectory files and when I removed those and its dependencies, background correctly set as we expected.
Now how can we keep our Textbox style overriding Telerik ResourceDirectory files?

Anyway thank you very much for your very quick help Chris. It really throws some lights for me on XAML styling.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:** I've only now noticed that you discussed this with Chris through comments, he pretty much asked you what I asked below.

Works with me:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="OutputTextBoxStyle" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="15" />
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="123123" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Style="{DynamicResource OutputTextBoxStyle}"/>
</Grid>
```

[image]

How does your TextBox actually look like (XAML)?

I suspect you've set the `Background` Property which is overriding the value that's inside your Style.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I think, I have spotted out the issue. When I commented the the line 

<ResourceDictionary Source="/Telerik.Windows.Themes.Office2013;component/Themes/System.Windows.xaml" />

in App.XAML, textbox backgroud appeared as expected.

Now need to get my style OutputTextBoxStyle should work keeping the above Telerik theme (uncommented).

i.e. How can I override all styles with OutputTextBoxStyle ?

Please correct me if am going on a wrong track?

Comment: Normally you can load as many styles from different libraries as you want, as long they don't share the same Key, which causes the last one that was loaded to override another style with the same Key. Try renaming your OutputTextBoxStyle to something else.